# Apply CSS to iframe parent (on same domain)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { padding:0px; }
</style>
<body>

<div>testing123</div>
<iframe src="page2.html"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to apply some js/css to page2.html that will change the `div { padding:0px; }` part of the parent?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to put jquery code into your `Iframe` load:

```
parent.$('body').find('div').css('padding', '10px');
```

On your html page `page2.html` put code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   parent.$('body').find('div').css('padding', '10px');
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend you add a non-jQuery answer as well, since it wasn't tagged.

Answer (score 0):

You can't affect the CSS of an iframed element. You would need to do it directly in the file

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite.. Trying to affect the iframe parent rather than the inner iframe. I want to apply code to page2.html that will affect the index.html file

Comment: You can't do that directly in CSS either, but if they're on the same domain, you could use script in the iframed page to append a new external css file (or just a style element with some CSS rules) to the parent page.

Comment: @hoverhand That will require JavaScript cloning all `style` tags as text nodes into the parent page, through `window.parent || parent ||
top`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you have to add the codes to page2.html even if on the same domain.

Comment: Can you share an example of how to control the ``div`` styling via the page2.html page?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

`$("div", top.document).css("padding", "10px");`

I do recommend giving your `div` an `id` to prevent screwing up the entire page's css.